# Копирование информации в бд

Tags: phpmyadmin, php

Можно ли копировать информацию что находится в табличке бд, и заносить эту копию в туже таблицу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3) SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table WHERE param=$param");
```

Comment: и вам спасибо =)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста ))

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into table_name select * from table_name where name = "Prikol"
```